# How do I check the type of an exception that I don't have available?

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I have an exception thrown from a package imported by another package, I do not have access to that exception's constructor but I do know that this exception might have a `statusCode` field on it. How do I access this field safely when using typescript 4.4's useUnknownInCatchVariables?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own class which would extend the `Error` class, and add a `statusCode` field to it. Then in the `catch` block you could check if the caught error is an `instance` of your error:

```js
import someExternalLibrary from 'some-external-library';

class PackageException extends Error {
  statusCode: number = 0;
}

try {
  someExternalLibrary.methodWhichThrowsError();
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof PackageException) {
      if (err.statusCode === 404) {
          // handle not found error
      } else if (err.statusCode === 403) {
          // handle forbidden error
      }
  }
}
```

[TS playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3arAw)

Comment: But what if I am not the one throwing the exception? I can't define the error type.

Comment: @Ziv if you are not throwing it, it doesn't mean that you can't catch it. If it's being thrown from a method in an external library, then just put that method inside a `try...catch` block and you will catch it.

Comment: I have updated my answer and included an example of what I meant in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Inside catch err can be of any type

```
try {
    // something
} catch (err: {statusCode: number}) {
        if (err.statusCode === 404) {
            // handle not found error
        } else if (err.statusCode === 403) {
            // handle forbidden error
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to specify the type to be any. I do think that having the type of err be unkown is a good idea.

Comment: @ziv updated my answer to remove any

Comment: dude, you just copy/pasted the example code from my answer and updated it slightly. Not cool